# Kubernetes and network control

Tags: docker, kubernetes, distributed-computing

I have some simple software which I need to distribute on about 20 physical servers. I'm planning on using Ansible+Docker for provisioning the servers. These tools does not quite cover my needs though; I need the software to be running at all times. If a box is out for any reason, another node needs to spawn a new instance. This is pretty much what any of the orchestration tools offers, but I also have some network constraints:

- I need some control over where the instances run. A node cannot run all the instances.
- It would be nice to prefer another node that is as close as possible to the failing node in the network

Is Kubernetes the right fit for this system?

Also, does the system work without the Kubernetes master? Can the master be redundant as well?

Comment: I think k8s does not really have mechanisms for those specific scheduler requirements yet. You can [assign pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/) to k8s worker nodes with certain labels, but this is not quite what you seem to need. Maybe Mesos or [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/) scheduler (though last time I tried Nomad it didn't seem production ready) have more features.

Comment: A Daemonset in Kubernetes will ensure a container POD runs on each node in a Kubernetes cluster. Does this fufill your needs? https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/daemons/

Comment: @fishi: Nomad looks quite promising. It seems I have a lot more control over what runs where. It also seems a bit more lightweight than Kubernetes.

Comment: Nomad solely focuses on container scheduling, rather than having a feature complete platform like k8s does. Obviously this also means that you would still somehow need to take care of things like loadbalancing and service discovery yourself. On the upside, Nomad integrates seamlessly with other HashiCorp tools, such as [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) for service discovery (a really nice tool btw). Last time I played around with Nomad though, it was still very young and didn't seem production-ready, so you should test it thoroughly.